# List all files with the same name and number of that files

Tags: filenames

I wonder if there is an easy command to list all files with the same names and number of that files? I would like to do it recursively and I do not mean concrete filename. I can imagine the output would look like this:

```
FILENAME   NUMBER
filename1    2
filename2    4
filename3    8
```

Answer (score 9):

Using GNU `find`:

```
find /some/path -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

Using POSIX `find`:

```
find /some/path -type f | sed 's~^.*/~~' | sort | uniq -c
```

This assumes your filenames don't contain newlines.

Comment: Alternative, with GNU tools and handling badly-behaved file names: `find "$@" '!' -type d -print0 | xargs -0 basename -za | sort -z | uniq -cz | sort -nzr | tr '\0' '\n'`  - I've also shown how to include filenames that are symlinks or devices, and to sort the final output numerically.  HTH.

Comment: wow, that `-c` option to `uniq` renders my script useless. Thanks, that'll be useful in future.

Comment: Whats its O-complexity? Is it O(n*n)? @lcd047

Comment: @Alper The solution has the same complexity as your `sort`.  Your question doesn't make much sense beyond that. :)

Answer (score 0):

since you cannot have files with the same name in the same directory, I assumed you have them in different directories (e.g. folder1/file folder2/file folder1/otherfile folder2/otherfile )

```
for name in NAME1 NAME2 NAME3 ; do
    echo -n $name \ \ \ 
    ls */$name | wc -l 
done
```

If they just have the same prefix (i.e. picture1 picture2 frame1 frame2 ), then it is almost the same:

```
for name in NAME1 NAME2 NAME3 ; do
    echo -n $name \ \ \ 
    ls $name* | wc -l
done
```

For the headline just preceed the whole thing with

```
echo FILENAME \ \ \ \ NUMBER
```

(it's BASH script of course)

---

[Update following requests in comments:]

```
#!/bin/bash

  # alternative 1
  # put filenames sorted and without double entries into array fnames
  fnames=( $( find -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort | uniq ) )
  # alternative 2: including folder names:
  ## fnames=( $( find -printf "%f\n" | sort | uniq ) )

  # count each names number of appearances:

  for (( i=0 ; i<=${#fnames[@]}-1 ; i++ )) ; do
    # alternative 1: files only
    number=$( find -type f -wholename "*/${fnames[$i]}" -printf "%f\n" | wc -l )
    # alternative 2: files and folders with same name
    ## number=$( find -wholename "*/${fnames[$i]}" -printf "%f\n" | wc -l )

    echo -e ${fnames[$i]} \ \ \ $number

  done
```

Comment: But assume that I do not know NAME1, NAME2, NAME3, can I somehow get all these repeating filenames ?

Comment: different folder and same names, or same folder and different names?

Comment: different directories, different depth of directories, same names

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Almost, it also list files that do not repeat, I mean number is 1. ;)

Comment: add a reverse grep then: `bash script | grep -v ' 1$' ` - but @lcd047's answer is far more elegant and could also be used with grep to exclude single appearances.